# Is it possible to cache authenticated resources _per user_ in a reverse proxy?

Tags: authentication, rest, caching, basic-authentication

We have a REST-ish (as in not very RESTful, but still accessing stuff by uri) service where each user has to authenticate itself in order to get access to some resource. Basically, the result of accessing a resource `http://server/do_something?q=foobar` will differ on the user.

The user is authenticated using HTTP Authentication (over TSL).

Each user here represents a high-volume web service, and so caching would be very beneficial for us. But after reading up on caching for it seems that the presence of an authentication header will prevent the resource from being cached.

That makes sense if one would look at just the URI, but the vitals here include the authentication header. So is there any way of doing this caching using fairly standard tools (Apache's mod_cache, Squid, etc)?

Comment: eh, maybe this belongs in serverfault?

Comment: I guess the only/simple way would be to make the user(id/name) part of the URI...

Answer (score 0):

We ended up creating virtual hosts per user, where the caching is done on each host:

- user1.myservice.net
- user2.myservice.net
- ...